# Expected an indented block after "if" statment in line 15

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pgzero
```

//Importing
import game
from random import randint
apple = Actor("apple")

```
def draw():
    screen.clear()
    apple.draw()

def place_apple():
    apple.x = randint(10, 800)
    apple.y = randint(10, 600)

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    if apple.collidepoint(pos):
    print("Good Shot!")
    place_apple()
    else:
        print("You Missed!")
        quit()
```

Comment: You are indeed missing an indent after your if statemnt. The lines print("Good Shot!") and place_apple() should be indented.

Comment: Have you considered indenting the block after the if statement on the noted line?

Answer (score -2):

You are indeed missing an indent after your if statement. It should be:

```
def on_mouse_down(pos):
    if apple.collidepoint(pos):
        print("Good Shot!")
        place_apple()
    else:
        print("You Missed!")
        quit()
```